# Cassandra 3.11.0 Implement a Simple Trigger

Tags: java, triggers, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nosql

This is to all the Cassandra ninjas here. Thank you in advance for your help!

I am trying to do something somewhat trivial, please let me know if this is possible at all

## Goal

For each **trade** a user makes, I would like to update another table/cf **positions** to reflect the new trade, and keep these actions atomic and in sync

i.e.

anytime an INSERT query runs

```
INSERT INTO mykeyspace.trades (stockID, quantity) VALUES ("AAPL", 100)
```

I would like to make sure the corresponding position table receives an increase of **quantity += 100**

(essentially querying the current value of the AAPL position and adding 100 to it)

## What I've Researched so Far

If this was a traditional RDBMS, this would be a vanilla use case for Triggers.

So I was glad to see that Cassandra provides the **ITrigger** interface

However, all documentations of how to implement **ITrigger** appears to be using an older API where the interface contract is

```
Collection<Mutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update);
```

However, in 3.11.0 I see the contract is

```
Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update);
```

Looking at the official **DataStax** website, I see a sample implementation for an **AuditTrigger** [HERE](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cassandra.git;a=blob_plain;f=examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java;hb=HEAD)

However, observe the line

```
TableMetadata metadata = Schema.instance.getTableMetadata(auditKeyspace, auditTable);
```

**TableMetadata** does not appear to be a class at least on **cassandra-all-3.11.0**

Any pointers or documentations would be greatly appreciate here! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use [batch](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) ? In Cassandra batch is used to achieve Atomicity.

Comment: Is there a notion of row locking? Say transactions are streaming from multiple instances through a queueing service ... we want each transaction to increase or decrease the 'balance' table. Does not seem like batching would ensure no race condition?

Comment: No there is no row locking. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43978441/2320144. Batch will not ensure race condition on   increase or decrease the 'balance' table. Also trigger will not help you. You could use [counter](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) for balanced table.

Comment: Also you could use [Lightweight transactions](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0). But it is very costly.

Comment: Understood, thank you for taking the time

Comment: Cassandra doesn't allow mixing counter and non counter updates in a batch, so batch cannot be useful here (unless the counter is updated using optimistic locking, which would be slow).