# How to achieve row level locking in cassandra

Tags: java, database, cassandra, locking

I have a Cassandra cluster setup like Node N1, Node N2 and Node N3

I have a user table, I need to write create a row level locking for it across the nodes in the cluster, So could you please guide me by answering the following questions?

1) What is the maximum level of locking possible in Cassandra?
2) What is lightweight transaction? How much it is possible to achieve row level locking?
3) Is there an alternate way to achieve the row level locking in Cassandra?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975775/cassandra-write-lock

Answer (score 4):

1. None, but you might stretch it to say column level.
2. It uses paxos for consensus and can perform conditional updates. It doesnt do locking. It will either succeed or not if another update occurred, if it doesnt succeed you can try again. If it does succeed everything in "transaction" (poor naming) will apply. However, theres still no isolation within it and if multiple columns in row are updated you may read between them being applied. [details here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html)
3. Design data model so you dont need locking.

Comment: How could you say design a data model will not need locking ? If we need a row level locking how to achieve that in Cassandra ?

Comment: strategies like event sourcing, crdt's, etc. Theres some good resources on data modeling at datastax academy (https://academy.datastax.com/) or youtube.  You can use LWTs in most cases for the situations that require concurrent safety (like updating a balance, making sure a username is unique etc), but it does come at a performance cost. I recommend doing as much as you can without it. Keep in mind things like updating a balance in bank accounts etc are not done by row locking but by logging every transaction and calculating total from it.

Comment: 1) How does cassandra does this  'updating a balance in bank accounts etc are not done by row locking but by logging every transaction and calculating total from it. ' ?                                                                                                                     2) What is paxos consensus protocol? How does it provides concurrent writes for a specific row?

Comment: Its actually does have optimistic locking with compare and swap, or CAS.  Although internally its more complex then that. Its explained in the [details here] above which explains it better thanI. Its kinda like in java having all the Atomic____ classes that are used in lock-free algorithms. You give a update and a condition and it either all happens or none of it does. For something like a balance its condition is the balance = what you read it as. If something else changed it since you read the balance and your update being applied, it fails to apply so you re-read it and try again.

Comment: 1) log every transaction and periodically record the "current" thats kept in memory or redis or something. Periodically flush this current. Theres really different approaches (ie lambda architecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_architecture). Store the values in C* in case of a failure to rebuild current. 2) paxos is really an implementation detail you dont need to worry about it but you can google it if interested and theres lots of resources. Its a distributed consensus algorithm used in many databases built to scale easily.

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html is good example under the conditional updates section for a "balance" kinda thing with lwts

Answer (score 2):

There is no transactions in cassandra, there is no locking.  There is however light weight transactions.  They're not great, the performance is worse and there are alot of tradeoffs.

Depending on what the use case is for this lock you could do:

`INSERT INTO User (userID, email) 
VALUES (‘MyGuid’, ‘user@example.com’)
IF NOT EXISTS;`

If the query returns an error/failure you would have to handle that, it won't just fail if someone inserts before you.  A failure also might mean that 1 of your nodes did get the write but not all of them.  LWT don't roll back.

Comment: 1) How is that light weight transcation provides row level locking?                 I am not able to understand from this artcile 'https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0'                                               2) Example : Considering this scenario, Thread 1 tries to read the row1 from user table, In the same time, Thread 2 tries to delete the row1 from the user table, How will you provide the locking for this using lightweight transcation and what is the query / syntax used?

Comment: You are also saying there is no locking, then why there is a performance hiccups when running the queries of lightweight transcation?

Comment: There are additional connections that need to be established to support the if not exists and return succesfully.

In your above example.  Consider soft deleting a user (use a isDeleted column).  Most of the time unless you're trying to support the right to forget you don't actually want to delete that data anyway.